# Can't connect to Virtual box remote screen on linux Fedora 17 host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, remote-desktop, display, remote

I get trouble to use virtualbox remote screen on a linux host. I activated server in settings->display->remotedisplay and the port is 33333.

Then on linux I do : 
$ rdesktop 127.0.0.1:33333
Autoselected keyboard map en-us
ERROR: 127.0.0.1: unable to connect

I have read info here http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html
I tryed various connections addresses and checked netstat, port scanning.
Also tryed to start the vm headless.
and still can't connect :(

Here is more info,
Thanks for your help in advance

$ uname -a
Linux rocky 3.6.10-2.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 11 18:07:34 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ vboxmanage -v
4.2.4_RPMFusionr81684

netstat -t -l -n

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58144           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54690           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::631                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::36465                :::*                    LISTEN

or, with resolving port name

netstat -t -l

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdoma:ipp *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdom:smtp *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:58144                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:54690                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ipp                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:36465              [::]:*                  LISTEN

Answer (score 0):

The IP number 127.0.0.1 is ONLY available on the current host you are running.  You can connect to yourself using this IP.  You cannot externally connect to a different host (virtual or external) using this IP address.

You'll have to find the IP address that was assigned to the virtual host and ssh to that host.

Comment: ok, thanks.
my local IP is 192.168.1.10 and I also tryed 
rdesktop 92.168.1.10:3333
and
rdesktop 92.168.1.16:3333 (it is the assigned IP to the virtualhost)

The host computer is my desktop running a windowsXP guest.
Thank you

Comment: I think this is not relevant. The RDP remote connection is a feature of the VirtualBox host application, not of the guest. The port will definitely be open on the host's IP address(es). @user184363 Could you post the result of `netstat -t -l`?

Comment: @billc.cn Of course I agree with you, the 33333 port should be openend on the host. I was trying to be sure im not missing anything